# Windows 7 display issue: blurry and messed up images and fonts

Tags: windows-7, display

If it is not the right space to post this, where can I post it?
I just installed Windows 7 SP1 on an old Thinkpad T400 and I am seeing display issues. I am currently on an external screen (VGA port) but displaying only on the laptop screen shows the same issue.

As you can see in the pictures some pixels are blurry and messed up. Then they come back and forth. I tried what is listed here: Display issues on multiple screens after Windows 7 Update KB4034664 (August 2017) in vain.

What else can I try?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update the Video Driver.

Run Clear Type - Display Properties.  (Go to Search and type in Clear Type).

Remember that Windows 7 does not fully update any more so that patches may be missing and not much you can do about that.

So on the machine you have you may have to accept what you have.

If you cannot solve it, then move to Windows 10 (runs on many machines) or Windows 11 (needs a newer machine). You may need a newer machine in any event.

Microsoft is not supporting Windows 7 except for corporations paying contracts to support it.

So once an individual's machine stops working correctly (for any number of reasons), then a newer, supported OS is the only answer

Comment: Try a modern OS. If the machine cannot run newer Windows versions, try another OS such as Linux. You can test from USB without needing to install.

Comment: Thanks, I've been using Linux for 15 years. Migrated an old machine to windows because I need it for a specific software.
Newer windows is not gonna run on this machine.
Clear type is on.
Vidéo driver is up to date.
Anything more I could try?

Comment: Not much else on the machine you have except a more modern machine

Comment: Can't believe that win 7 would not give a correct display on this machine. It was running on it a long time ago.

Comment: If Drivers and Clear Type did not work, then as you just installed (reinstalled) Windows 7 and no updates / patches any more available, then that is likely the reason as I mentioned in my answer. Once your OS has issues that cannot be repaired, upgrade to a supported OS is the only solution

Comment: @user130482 “Can't believe that win 7 would not give a correct display on this machine. It was running on it a long time ago.” Then some kind of specific drivers are missing and installing plain Windows 7 won’t deal with that. Search [here](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds000918-access-help-for-windows-7-thinkpad-r400-r500-t400-t400s-t500-w500) to see of any Lenovo specific drivers might address this issue.

Comment: In addition to Drivers (already noted), Windows 7 is no longer properly updatable  as Microsoft is determined to stop Windows 7 (again, already noted)